# Get values .env and assign them to docker-compose.yml but database cannot be connected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, .env

I can get values named DATABASE_USERNAME and DATABASE_PASSWORD form .env file and define them in docker-compose.yml file.

Here is my `.env` shown below

```
DATABASE_USERNAME=value
DATABASE_PASSWORD=value
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` shown below

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env  # Use the .env file for environment variables
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bookdelivery
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_PORT: 3307
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - bookDeliveryNetwork

  bookdelivery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: bookdelivery
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env  # Use the .env file for environment variables
    ports:
      - "1221:1221"
    environment:
      - server.port=1221
      - spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      - spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3307/bookdelivery
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - bookDeliveryNetwork


networks:
  bookDeliveryNetwork:
```

Here is the docker compose config result

```
name: bookdelivery                                     
services:                                              
  bookdelivery:                                        
    build:                                             
      context: C:\Users\Noyan\IdeaProjects\bookdelivery
      dockerfile: Dockerfile                           
    container_name: bookdelivery                       
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: value
      DATABASE_USERNAME: value
      server.port: "1221"
      spring.datasource.password: value
      spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3307/bookdelivery
      spring.datasource.username: root
    networks:
      bookDeliveryNetwork: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 1221
      published: "1221"
      protocol: tcp
    restart: on-failure
  database:
    container_name: database
    environment:
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: value
      DATABASE_USERNAME: value
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bookdelivery
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: value
      MYSQL_PORT: "3307"
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: value
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    networks:
      bookDeliveryNetwork: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 3306
      published: "3307"
      protocol: tcp
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: C:\Users\Username\IdeaProjects\bookdelivery\db
      target: /var/lib/mysql
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
networks:
  bookDeliveryNetwork:
    name: bookdelivery_bookDeliveryNetwork
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`,

I got this issue shown below

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Files named `.env` should be automatically picked up. You don't have to specify it as a property unless it's a different file/directory. Everything you described sounds correct. How are you starting your containers? What's the output of `docker compose config`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I revised the post. Can you look through it? I cannot connect to MySQL database

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I want to share some screenshots. ibb.co/QfHZSdg ibb.co/tp9Q9Pk . As you can see, ControllerTest cannot work because it needs to connect mysql database through test container.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting an environment file and setting environment variables in the compose file?

**remove:**

```
environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

How you have it above [Substitutes from the shell](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-from-the-shell), not from the .env file

**Just put them all in the .env file** or atleast the ones you want hidden.

Docs page for environment variables is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/)

Comment: I revised the post. Can you look through it? I cannot connect to MySQL database

Comment: I want to share some screenshots. ibb.co/QfHZSdg ibb.co/tp9Q9Pk . As you can see, ControllerTest cannot work because it needs to connect mysql database through test container.